# Java Bean "is" removed from property name

Tags: java

I've got a boolean on a class of "isMarketed".

When I'm returning this in a RESTful endpoint the object is returned like so:

```
{..., "marketed": true, ...}
```

But when I'm creating the object (by passing in some JSON and using GSON to make the object), it is expecting me to provide it as so:

```
{..., "isMarketed": true, ...}
```

Can someone please explain why this is?

Comment: Is it a Boolean wrapper type or a boolean primitive?

Comment: In Java Beans boolean primitive follow the convention "isWhatever" but Boolean is object and uses "getWhatever". I'm not sure if is related with your behavior. Maybe the way getters, setters are written. Please post your code.

Comment: Apologies, I'm using a primitive boolean as opposed to Boolean. I've updated my question.

Comment: Is your RESTful service using a different JSON serialization library to GSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design - methods with certain prefixes like `is` (convention for the `boolean/Boolean` return type), `get` and `set` get mapped as the getters or setters of the property specified after the prefix by the Javabean classes for the particular bean object. By doing this, genetic utility Javabean get and set methods that take in bean objects and argument names can retrieve the properties in a normalised manner.

I assume the libraries you're using are using this Javabean stuff, so wouldn't be using the full method names. The internal fields aren't accessed directly because getters and setters may have extra logic or may work with fields that don't actually exist.

```
void    setActive(boolean active)
boolean isActive()
void    setPlayer(Player player)
Player  getPlayer()
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this so thoroughly, Chris. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll remove the **is** from the name of the property. Because it is confusing.
It's like name a field as `getBread` when the field should be named just `bread`.

I think the correct name for the field should be `marketed`, the getter `isMarketed()` and the setter `setMarketed(boolean marketed)`.

Comment: That's the way to go. I also suffered this problem while working with hibernate. Removing the "is"  got me over.

Comment: Thanks, this did solve the problem along with the information provided by Chris.